# Are there pairs $(x,n)$ for which :$x^n=0\bmod x+n$ with $x \neq n$ are positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I have tried to find relationship for congruence between $x$ and it's power , such that I want know if there are  pairs $(x,n)$  satisfying : $x^n=0\bmod (x+n)$ with $x, n$ are positive integers , then my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >     Are there  pairs $(x,n)$ for which   :$x^n=0\bmod x+n$  with $x \neq n$ are positive integers?

Comment: Umpteen. Eg $(x,n)=(2,2),(2,6),(2,14),(2,30),\dots$ or $(3,6),(3,24),(3,78),\dots$ or $(5,20),(5,120)\dots$. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Thanks , according to your exampls , it's seems that  : x, n  arn't comprime $